# Where does the -и ending in "Ныне отпущаеши..." come from?

Tags: морфология

In Rachmaninov's [Vespers](http://www.belcanto.ru/or-rachmaninov-bdenie.html), I stumbled upon this line:

> Ныне отпущаеш**и** раба Твоего...

Which should mean "Now you dismiss your servant". (It's a quote from Bible, that's how I know.) What baffles me here is the -и ending that I marked in bold. I would be expecting "отпущаеш**ь**" instead. Where does that -и come from? Is it just an archaic ending no longer in use? (Since it's a biblical quote, it could very well be.)

P. S.: I don't really know Russian. I understand it just by being able to read Cyrillic and relate to my native language of Czech, which happens to be Slavic as well. Hence I'm sorry if I missed something basic in here.

Comment: in modern Russian it would be much more different "отпуСКаешЬ"

Comment: no worries, you got it right )

Comment: Thank you :). I'm now quite positive that it's quite an archaic text. There's another line: "яко **видеста** очи мои", which looks pretty much like a dual, both according what I know about Czech and the nice conjugation table.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes it's the archaic form**. In Old Russian it had been the form for the second person (one that is used with `ты`) - roughly speaking where we now have `шь` in modern Russian it was `ши`. in Old Russian (or [Old East Slavic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_East_Slavic), whatever you name it).

[image]

As a side-note, when I was a kid and first time heard 
[`Камо грядеши`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE_%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B8) it sounded very exotic and unfamiliar to me, my first thought was even this is, don't know, Japanese or something like that.